# vim: Run multiple commands based off of one :global command

Tags: vim, vi, ex

Apologies if this has been posted already, for I cannot find an answer, even on the vim wiki.

Is there a way I can run multiple commands in vim command-line mode off of a single `:g` search?

For example,

```
:%g/foo/ s/bar/\=@a/g | exe "norm /cat\<enter>\"ayiw"
```

Which (for what I intend it to do) should, on every line matching `foo`, replace `bar` with the contents of register `a`, and **then** find the next iteration of `cat` (even if it is many lines ahead), and put the surrounding word into register `a`.

Instead, this specific syntax completes the subsitution command using the current contents of the initial `a` register, and then executes the normal mode command on a single line (after the substitution has been completed).

This example is not my specific use-case but shows one instance where this functionality is useful. I realize I could put it all into a single `exe`, i.e., `%g/foo/exe "norm :s/bar/\\=@a/g\<enter>/cat\<enter>\"ayiw"`, but I would like to do it the first way, as I feel it is more flexible.

I would prefer to do this using vanilla vim, but if a plugin exists for this, that is an okay alternative. Does anybody know if there is syntax to do such a thing?

Comment: Interesting. Normally, the `norm ...` should be executed once on each matching line, but it really looks like it's only executed once. The `/.../` search seems to cause this.

Answer (score 1):

Okay a "little bit" dirty, but does this work for you?

```
:let list = split(execute('g/cat/p'), '\n') | g/foo/ s/bar/\=matchstr(remove(list, 0), '\s\d\+\s\zs.*')/g
```

It first reads all occurences of `cat` save them in a list.
Then replace the first `bar` with the first cat... and so on.

The dirty part ist the `matchstr` command. the `g//p` also returns a number for the result so the list looks like this:

```
 1 cat
 2 cat
 3 cat
 ...
```

that's why we have to remove a bit from the front. I would love to hear if someone knows a clean solution for that (I am also interested in a clean vimscript solution, does not have to be a oneliner).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (at least for multiple :s commands applied to a single :g). Example:

```
" SHORT STORY TITLES to single word of CapitalizedWords within <h3>s
.,$g/^\L\+$/s/[^A-Z0-9 ]\+//ge|s/\u\+/\L&/ge|s/\<\l\+\>/\u&/ge|s/ \+//ge|s/.*/<h3>&<\/h3>/
```